# split a list permuting over all possible sublists

Tags: python, permutation

A little riddle: you have six packets of 6, 12, 14, 15, 23 and 29 cards. Some packets have cards of pigs and others packets have cards of foxes. If you remove a packet, the cards of pigs are double than cards of foxes. Which packet you must remove?

I need iterate over the packets, delete it from list and create / permute over the possible subgroups to find the correct combination.

The following code resolve the problem, but I get repeated successes and I'm sure exist a more efficient and elegant way to write it. Ilustrate me, please!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import permutations

packets = [6, 12, 14, 15, 23, 29]

for position, packet in enumerate(packets):
    hypothesis = list(packets)
    del(hypothesis[position])
    # the next conditional is not really needed, 
    # only use it to save some operations
    if sum(hypothesis) % 3 == 0:
        for item in permutations(hypothesis, 5):
            if sum(item[:2]) * 2 == sum(item[2:]):
               print(item[:2], "and", item[2:], "removed: ", packets[position])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check for possible combinations using dynamic programming solution of [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Just solve `subset_sum(hypothesis, sum(hypothesis) // 3)`